# Resolution problem on Lenovo y50-70 with 4K display

Tags: lenovo

I have lenovo y50-70 with 4K display.
How can I configure OS to have full resolution with optimized scaling? 
And how can I change the size of fonts in TUI and in GRUB menu? It's so tiny I barely can read it!

Can't find anything in web, and I'm quite new in linux, please help ;)

Comment: elementary OS freya does not support 4k and HiDPI displays.This will be fixed in elementary OS Loki (0.4)